# Why won't a gradle war pick up an artifact from a dependent project

Tags: java, gradle

In `project 1` I have a source set that goes into it's own jar

```
sourceSets {
    sample {
        java {
            srcDir 'sample/java'
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    }
}
task sampleJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'sample'
    from sourceSets.sample.output
}

artifacts {
    archives sampleJar
}
```

When I do gradle build, both the main jar and sample jar are built.

In another project, `project 2` that is a web app, which has a compile dependency on project 1

```
compile project(path:':modules:project1', transitive: false)
```

I want it to pull in the main jar file from project 1 and the sample jar file that is called out as an artifact.

When I run `>gradle war` it only pulls in the main jar file from project 1, it doesn't bring in the sample jar file.

Any idea why?